# Map numpad to real number keys on linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, numpad

I want the numpad numbers to be exactly the same as the regular numbers, so if I press `Shift+1` on the numpad I want `!` to be printed. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I could figure out the answer by following [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/a/24930) instructions, I'll let here the answer just in case it is useful for someone else.

numbers 1-7 (english layout):

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 87 = 1 exclam'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 88 = 2 at'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 89 = 3 numbersign'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 83 = 4 dollar'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 84 = 5 percent'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 85 = 6 asciicircum'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 79 = 7 ampersand'
```

It has no sense for number 8 to be `*` as in english layout since it
already is on the numpad I binded it to what it would be in spanish
layout instead which is: `(`. Same thing happens with 9 which would be
the same as: `)` and 0 which would be: `=`.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 80 = 8 parenleft'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 81 = 9 parenright'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 90 = 0 equal'
```

Optionally you could bind number 2 to `"` when used with shift and `@`
when used with alt (It would overwrite original behaviour of course):

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 88 = 2 quotedbl NoSymbol NoSymbol at at'
```

makes changes persistent:

```
xmodmap -pke >~/.Xmodmap
```

PS: to actually do those changes permanent you should execute `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` somewhere in your `~/.Xinitrc` file and/or whenever you change your layout with `setxkbmap`

Comment: If you are completely satisfied with the solution, you could select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: It seems like I have to wait 48 hours from the time I asked it (still 21 hours left). http://oi57.tinypic.com/e67x34.jpg. I will tick it as answered once that time is passed.